# How to set-up email archiving/journaling for all users on Outlook 365 e-mail?

Tags: email, outlook.com, office-365, outlook-365

How to set-up email archiving on Outlook 365 e-mail on a custom domain? I don't mean GoDaddy 365 emails.

This would let one search all-emails on the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to [setup email for your custom domain.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/change-email-address?view=o365-worldwide)

Next, [set up what Microsoft refers to as "in-place archiving"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/enable-archive-mailboxes?view=o365-worldwide) which might be what you need.

According to the [Microsoft Exchange service description](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-service-description?redirectedfrom=MSDN#features-available-to-some-plans), in-place archiving is only available on some plans. Exchange is the email service behind Outlook 365.

It looks like to me you could choose one of the three plans for each user you'd like to set up email archiving for.

- [Online Archiving add-on](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/exchange/microsoft-exchange-online-archiving-email?rtc=1)
- [Exchange Online Plan 2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/exchange/compare-microsoft-exchange-online-plans)
- [Microsoft 365 E3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/e3?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab)

You can [create up to 400 email addresses for each user](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/add-another-email-alias-for-a-user?view=o365-worldwide).